# Any affine algebraic group is linear.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

It is a well-known result that any affine algebraic group is a closed subgroup of some $\mathrm{Gl}_n(\Bbbk)$. However, I would like to see a proof for that, so I looked it up in various books, more precisely in

- Procesi, *Lie Groups - An Approach through Invariants and Representations*, the theorem on page 172
- Borel, *Linear Algebraic Groups*, 2nd Edition, Proposition 1.10
- Alexander H.W. Schmitt, *Geometric Invariant Theory and Decorated Principal Bundles*, Theorem 1.1.3.3

The proof is always more or less the same and always lacks an important argument (in my opinion). Let me give you a quick overview:

If $\mu:G\times G\to G$ denotes the multiplication morphism and $\Bbbk[G]=\Bbbk[f_1,\ldots,f_n]$ then we may assume that the $f_i$ span a $G$-invariant subspace $V\subseteq\Bbbk[G]$. One can show that the comorphism $\mu^\sharp:\Bbbk[G]\to\Bbbk[G]\otimes\Bbbk[G]$ maps $V$ into $\Bbbk[G]\otimes V$ and thus,
$$ \mu^\sharp(f_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n \psi_{ij} \otimes f_j $$
for certain $\psi_{ij}\in\Bbbk[G]$. One then maps $g$ to the matrix $\Psi_g$ with entries $\psi_{ij}(g)$.

Now my question is: **Why is this a homomorphism of groups?**

I can tell you what I have done so far. One may consider the triple multiplication morphism $\nu:G\times G\times G\to G$ which is just $\nu:=\mu\circ(\mathrm{id}\times\mu)$, so we get
$$\begin{align*}
\nu^\sharp(f_i) &= (\mathrm{id}\times\mu)^\sharp\left(\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^n \psi_{ij} \otimes f_j\right) =
 \sum_{j=1}^n \psi_{ij} \otimes \mu^\sharp(f_j)
\\ &=
\sum_{j=1}^n \psi_{ij} \otimes \sum_{k=1}^n \psi_{jk} \otimes f_k
= \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum\nolimits_{j=1}^n \psi_{ij} \otimes \psi_{jk}\right) \otimes  f_k 
\end{align*}$$
so
$f_i(abc) =  \sum_{k=1}^n (\Psi_a\Psi_b)_{ik} \cdot f_k(c)$. Conversely, we may also understand $abc$ as the product of $ab$ with $c$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (\Psi_a\Psi_b)_{ik} \cdot f_k(c) = f_j(abc) &= \sum_{k=1}^n (\Psi_{ab})_{ik} \cdot f_k(c).
\end{align*}$$
Now, what we need are elements $c_j\in Z(f_k\mid k\ne j)\setminus Z(f_j)$ to show that $\Psi_a\Psi_b=\Psi_{ab}$. I have a vague feeling that $f_j$ can not be contained in $(f_k\mid k\ne j)$ because $G$ acts linearly on $V$, but for some reason I am stuck. So my question is:

- Can you finish my proof, i.e. show that $Z(f_k\mid k\ne j)\setminus Z(f_j)\ne \emptyset$ or equivalently, $f_j\notin(f_k\mid k\ne j)$?
- If not, can you give an alternative proof?

Comment: Have you consulted the original sources? Have you looked at Milne's script on algebraic groups?

Comment: I don't know the original sources, but in my experience, a graduate text book rather works out *more* details, not less, than the original paper. Still, I'd give it a look if I knew what paper it was. I also looked through Milne's stuff and I couldn't really easily identify the statement in any of his notes.

Comment: You should also look at Humphrey's book, which contains (if I recall) much the same argument as Giulio's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I think the idea is this. What does it mean to find an injective homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{GL}(W)$? It means to find a faithful representation $W$ of $G$. Somehow, the intuition tells me that the $V$ you are talking about is the right $W$, because it is spanned by elements that describe well $G$.

In fact, this is right: if an element $g$ fixes $V$, it fixes all of $k[G]$, hence it must be the identity. So we have an injective homomorphism (of groups, not talking of algebraic structure yet)

$$\rho:G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$$

Now, what coefficients do the matrices of $\rho$ have? Well, we may suppose that the $f_i$'s are a basis of $V$ (they generate, so I can extract a basis). Now,

$$(\rho(g)f_i)(h)=f_i(hg)=\sum_j\psi_{i,j}\otimes f_j(g,h)=\sum_j\psi_{i,j}(g)f_j(h)$$
hence
$$\rho(g)f_i=\sum_j\psi_{i,j}(g)f_j$$
So $\rho(g)=(\psi_{i,j}(g))_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$, and $\rho$ is in fact an injective homomorphism of algebraic groups.

Comment: This looks really good! Thanks for tending to this very old question of mine and giving a satisfying answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @GiulioBresciani, why $f_i(hg) = \sum_j \psi_{i,j} \otimes f_j(g,h)$? I think that since $f_i = \sum_j \psi_{i,j} \otimes f_j$, we have $f_i(hg) = \sum_j \psi_{i,j}(h) \otimes f_j(g)$. I am confused. Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is $\mu^\#f_i=\sum_j \psi_{i,j} \otimes f_j$, and hence $f_i(hg)= (\mu^\#f_i)(g,h)=\sum_j(\psi_{i,j} \otimes f_j)(g,h)=\sum_j\psi_{i,j}(g)f_j(h)$

Comment: @GiulioBresciani, thank you very much.